# Magento Shopping Cart "alert ##" rules are somehow being automatically generated

Tags: magento, alert, shopping-cart, rules

Over the past couple of months, we seem to be getting all these automatically generated shopping cart rules being created. They have the name of "Alert #691", "Alert #697" etc. The incrementation appears to be a bit random (but always increases). We get about 2-5 of these rules per day.

They appear to be giving a 5% discount, but none of these have ever been used by a customer.

I have no idea what would be causing this, does anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this. We have a module called Aitoc Abandoned Cart - apparantly it sends a 5% discount code on the 3rd email asking the user to retreive their abandoned cart.